# Проблема с bitmam.save и строками

Tags: c++, c, bitmap, screenshots, bitmapimage

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
 
#include <gdiplus.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
#pragma comment(lib, "GdiPlus.lib") /* наш многострадальный lib-файл */
using namespace Gdiplus; /* как хочешь, но мне не в кайф постоянно писать Gdiplus:: */
 
 
static const GUID png = 
{ 0x557cf406, 0x1a04, 0x11d3, { 0x9a, 0x73, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf8, 0x1e, 0xf3, 0x2e } }; 
 
 
int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    
HDC scrdc, memdc; 
HBITMAP membit;
// Получаем HDC рабочего стола
// Параметр HWND для рабочего стола всегда равен нулю.
scrdc = GetDC(0);
// Определяем разрешение экрана
int Height, Width;
Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
// Создаем новый DC, идентичный десктоповскому и битмап размером с экран.
memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
SelectObject(memdc, membit);
// Улыбаемся... Снято!
BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
HBITMAP hBitmap;
hBitmap =(HBITMAP) SelectObject(memdc, membit);
 Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);
bitmap.Save(L"c:\\screen.png", &png);

DeleteObject(hBitmap);

//GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
return 0;
}
```

И так суть проблемы. нашёл на форуме этот код. я хочу сделать несколько скриншотов с разными названиями, но когда я пытаюсь сделать например так:

```
string str = "screen" + i + ".png";
bitmap.Save(str, &png);
```

оно не работает, другие способы объедения строк тоже не работают. Я нашёл инфу про то что это должно быть в wchar_t, но даже если я вставлю не string, а wсhar_t, то всё также не будет работать. Пожалуйста подскажите, что можно сделать.

upd: если `string str = "screen" + std::to_string(i) + ".png"`
то:

> IntelliSense: отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "Gdiplus::Bitmap::Save", соответствующие списку аргументов
> типы аргументов: (std::string, const GUID *)
> тип объекта: Gdiplus::Bitmap

Comment: string str = "screen" + std::to_string(i) + ".png";

Comment: не работает....

Comment: 4 IntelliSense: отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "Gdiplus::Bitmap::Save", соответствующие списку аргументов
            типы аргументов: (std::string, const GUID *)
            тип объекта: Gdiplus::Bitmap

Comment: Видимо надо str.c_str() - это char*   bitmap.Save(str.c_str(), &png);

Comment: error C3867: std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str: в вызове функции отсутствует список аргументов; используйте "&std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>::c_str" для создания указателя на член

Comment: написал ответ, если всё ОК - то ставьте галочку (принимайте как ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечу куском кода:

```
int main()
{
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    
HDC scrdc, memdc; 
HBITMAP membit;

scrdc = GetDC(0);

int Height, Width;
Height = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
Width = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);

memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(scrdc);
membit = CreateCompatibleBitmap(scrdc, Width, Height);
SelectObject(memdc, membit);

BitBlt(memdc, 0, 0, Width, Height, scrdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
HBITMAP hBitmap;
hBitmap =(HBITMAP) SelectObject(memdc, membit);

Bitmap *bitmap = new Bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);

int i = 1;
string str = "screen" + std::to_string(i) + ".png";

int wchars_num = MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , str.c_str() , -1, NULL , 0 );
wchar_t* wstr = new wchar_t[wchars_num];
MultiByteToWideChar( CP_UTF8 , 0 , str.c_str() , -1, wstr , wchars_num );
            
Image *img = (Image*)bitmap;
img->Save(wstr, &png, nullptr);

delete[] wstr;
delete bitmap;

DeleteObject(hBitmap);

GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если всё ОК - то ставте галочку зелёную